# динамическая загрузка функций из DLL в Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, dll

по условию задачи необходимо разработать приложение на Windows Forms, используя Visual C++ 2010, которое позволяло бы проводить тестирование перечнем вопросов. также по условию задачи требуется реализовать код проверки правильности ответов на некоторые вопросы из перечня в DLL-ке, и обращаться к этому коду из первого проекта.

DLL-ка экспортирует пять однотипных функций, выглядящих так:

```
bool __cdecl eval1(bool,bool,bool,bool,int)
bool __cdecl eval2(bool,bool,bool,bool,int)
bool __cdecl eval3(bool,bool,bool,bool,int)
bool __cdecl eval4(bool,bool,bool,bool,int)
bool __cdecl eval5(bool,bool,bool,bool,int)
```

затем, в визуальном приложении, пишется такой код:

```
// в начале файла окна
typedef bool (__cdecl f_eval)(bool,bool,bool,bool,int);
// затем в некоторой функции
HINSTANCE hGetProcDLL = LoadLibrary(L"qst12345.dll");
if(!hGetProcDLL){
    MessageBox::Show("Не найдена библиотека проверки корректности ответов");
    return;
}
f_eval* eval1 = (f_eval*)GetProcAddress(hGetProcDLL, "eval1");
if(!eval1){
    MessageBox::Show("Не найдена функция проверки ответа первого вопроса");
    return;
} else { ... }
```

и во время работы приложения стабильно вижу свое сообщение "Не найдена функция проверки ответа первого вопроса".

не могу понять, что не так...

Comment: *"DLL-ка экспортирует "* - как вы это проверяли?

Comment: Попробуй "_eval1".  При использовании `__cdecl` к именам добавляется знак подчёркивания, по крайней мере так сказано здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/cdecl

Comment: 1. https://prnt.sc/svifhe - скриншот подтверждения экспортирования функций.
2. добавление "_" к имени искомой функции в вызове GetProcAddr ничего не поменяло

Comment: А теперь снимите флажок Undecorate.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/svip7f

Comment: Вот видите - экспортируется вовсе не `eval1`, а крякозябры. Объявляйте функции как `extern "C"` чтобы убрать декорирование

Comment: спасибо, заработало